# Select empty area between multiple SVG path with jQuery

Tags: jquery, svg

Simplified, I have 4 svg paths which have created a rectangle ([schematic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktf1b.png)).
How can I select the transparent area (Gray inner rectangle) of this rectangle by jQuery click in area?
I need its Top, left, length and width.

```html
<svg height="100px" version="1.1" width="500px">
       <path d="M0,0 10,0 10,100 0,100 Z"></path>
       <path d="M10,90 400,90 400,100 10,100 Z"></path>
       <path d="M10,0 400,0 400,10 10,10 Z"></path>
       <path d="M400,0 400,100 410,100 410,0 Z"></path>
    </svg>
```

Footnote: I can create a path for an empty area. But due to the complexities of the final shape, it continues to face problems.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

You can have an event listener on the entire svg and then deciding wht to do based on the nodeName (or something else (like class name) that is not the path).

#### Vanilla JS

```js
document.querySelector('svg').addEventListener('click', e => {
  switch(e.target.nodeName){
    case 'svg':
      console.log(e.clientX,',', e.clientY);
      break;
    case 'path':
      console.log('a path');
      break;
  }
});
```

```html
<svg height="100px" version="1.1" width="500px">
  <path d="M0,0 10,0 10,100 0,100 Z"></path>
  <path d="M10,90 400,90 400,100 10,100 Z"></path>
  <path d="M10,0 400,0 400,10 10,10 Z"></path>
  <path d="M400,0 400,100 410,100 410,0 Z"></path>
</svg>
```

#### jQuery

```js
$('svg').click(function(e){
  switch(e.target.nodeName){
    case 'svg':
      console.log(e.clientX,',', e.clientY);
      break;
    case 'path':
      console.log('a path');
      break;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg height="100px" version="1.1" width="500px">
  <path d="M0,0 10,0 10,100 0,100 Z"></path>
  <path d="M10,90 400,90 400,100 10,100 Z"></path>
  <path d="M10,0 400,0 400,10 10,10 Z"></path>
  <path d="M400,0 400,100 410,100 410,0 Z"></path>
</svg>
```